# Home Voip GV service/Phones not working with Cat5e wiring

Tags: wiring, data-wiring, internet, phone-wiring

General networking.  Landline telephone number using a digital voip google voice service box.  I want the GV box and phone moved into the hall bedroom.   I can’t get a dial tone on my landline telephone in one room, the hall bedroom that has Cat 5e wiring.   I do get a dial tone on my landline telephones in other rooms of the house that have RJ11 old school wiring.

Hall bedroom:  2009 an outside wall 4 pair Cat 5e wire was installed and originally used for telephone service ONLY connected to exterior At&t demarc box.  In 2017 At&t installed a 4 way keystone jack.  One pair was for broadband, one pair for phone, one pair for fax machine, the 4th pair was not used.  This 4 keystone jack, GV box, & landline phone worked in this hall brm.

2019 new service provider and a new location for router, from hall bedroom to hall communication closet.  A switch, router, GV box and phone was located near the ceiling on a shelf over a cloths closet and about 20 feet from the exterior Dmarc box.  A customer supplied Cat 5e wire is laying up in the attic from the Demarc to the new router location and is ready for future termination.  A decision was made to install new Cat 5e wire in 4 rooms of the house.  Not using wi-fi at this time.  Included in this 4 room wire install was an inside wall cat 5e (only 3 pair currently is working and one pair is broken along the wire line, up in the attic).

2021 Hurricane Ida hit.  We had damage.  The GV box and phone was moved into a back bedroom.  Now I want the GV box and phone moved into the hall bedroom.   The switch and router are still in communication closet.  I have worked on the keystone jack and the Demarc so many times and tried so many adjustments….I have forgotten what was done.  When I plug a corded phone in the test RJ11 outlet of the demarc…...no dial tone.  When I move the demar Cat 5e green with white and green pair from one RING and TIP to another RING and TIP…...no dial tone on 4 way keystone phone outlet.   When I punch down different color wire pairs T-568B in the keystone jack….no dial tone.  I have changed the keystone connector….no dial tone.  I have checked the RJ11 wires and tried different cables.  No matter what I do I can’t get a dial tone from the hall brm. 4 way Cat 5e keystone jack.

Comment: Curious: What VOIP box are you using for GV?   Just curious.  I have an old Obi one that still works great but they're not sold or supported any more and there is no replacement.

Comment: I tried answering this, but my answer evades your question somewhat by suggesting a workaround.  An excellent one IMO but still.   If you want help debugging your wiring you should rewrite the question with a lot less history and just describe what you have, what works, what testing you have done and what does not work.

Comment: Your description of what you are doing with the wiring is...essentially useless, and I'm a telephone and network wiring guy. Pictures could help. Or perhaps you are not using the white/blue pair (4,5) when you are trying to get dialtone on an RJ45, and that's the **only** pair that's going to give you dialtone to a standard RJ11 phone plug with standard RJ45 jack wiring. If you have VOIP service, the demarc will have data, not dialtone. The dialtone would come from the GV box.

Comment: You guys are the best.  Thank you.  The first comment helped the most.  “The dial tone comes from the GV box ”.  Moved the GV box#202 and phone to hall brm.  Power a/c to GV box.  Moved interior wall Cat5e ethernet keystone cable(this was originally plugged into the pc) to GV internet port.  Patch cable from GV Lan to pc.  Plug Rj11 cable from exterior wall Cat 5e keystone jack to GV Phone.  Pick up phone.  Dial Tone.  Now the phone in the hall brm. rings but the other phones on the old school wiring do not ring.  Con't on next comment.

Comment: Would like to have the exterior wall Cat 5e 2 pair data wires connected and working in the demarc.  The Cat 5e wire, that is laying up in the attic, would have to be connected from the demarc to the router.  My problem is where to drill a hole from the inside of the attic space to the existing hole where all the wires (coax phone service cable, one cat 5e, several twisted colored old school phone wiring) enter the demarc.  A piece of plywood is covering the 2x4’s on the interior of the attic space.  I can see where they are in the attic space but they disappear under the edge of the plywood.

Comment: Exterior demarc is installed much higher than where the wires are sandwiched under the plywood. Then once I guess where to drill the hole, how do I connect the wiring cat 5e wiring to the demarc?    
This is how the hall brm. exterior wall Cat 5e wiring connects to the demarcation point:  The Grn & Grn/white cat of the keystone jack to the Grn Ring & Grn/white to Tip of Demarc. The org&org/white and the brown&brn/white are not connected to anything. The blue&blue/white are connected together in a clip. From the clip is a white and violet wire that goes to the non-customer side of the NIB.

Comment: I might not have that correct.  The org&org/white might be in another clip, maybe with the solid blue.  If I could get the cat 5e data wiring to demarc right, I could have two ethernet connections in this hall brm.  One for the GV box and one for the pc. 
I can barely put this in writing…..how do you decipher what I say and patiently answer my questions?

Answer (score 4):

##### By far the easiest solution

Put the VOIP widget next to your switch in the closet.   Buy a [DECT6 phone sytem](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=dect%206%20phone%20system).   Put the base station also in the closet next to your switch, and plug it *directly* into the VOIP box with a brand new RJ11 patch cord, probably that comes with it.  Put the phones wherever you want.

Ta Da.  You rely on absolutely NONE of your home wiring for ethernet or phone.  If you need wired phones for some reason you can put an RJ11 tee on the VOIP box and then wire that to your house phone wiring, so at least the new wireless handsets don't rely on that.

##### Next best

If for some reason you really want to use your old wired phones, you should still put the VOIP box in the closet and still put an RJ11 Tee on it and still put one phone, any one you can, in the closet there plugged directly into it.  This gives you a baseline for testing.  Then you use the tee to connect to your home phone wiring, and ask a new question here, *only about that*, if you can't get it to work.   You have a working VOIP box with a phone plugged directly into it and working, you don't have to write such a long question.  You just have to figure out what's wrong with your old phone wiring.  IMO what's wrong is that you're still using it at all! :)